# How do I further diagnose TCP connectivity (timeout) problems? (ICMP, DNS work fine)

Tags: network, tcp

I have two Macs behind a cable modem/WAP. One works fine. The other is able to ping servers but is unable to telnet to them. For instance pinging `what.org` works fine but I get `operation timed out` errors when I `wget what.org` or `telnet what.org 80`. And `nmap what.org -Pn` says host is up but all ports are filtered. I'm pretty sure this is a problem with the computer, not with the modem/router. Also, strangely some of my Chrome tabs can still reload, duplicate, and function, like google, Gcal and Gmail, but other's can't, and all new domains fail with `Error 118 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT): The operation times out.`. Skype chat and dropbox work. How can I further diagnose this problem?

Answer (score 1):

First step: check that Mac n°2 is connected with the network interface you think it should (i.e. Ethernet and not AirPort or anything else).

If you are using the famous `Automatic` network configuration you are never sure on which interface your computer is talking or replying.
For example, your Mac n°2 might well be plugged toward the Internet through your neighbour Wi-Fi connection.

Comment: Thank you. It's wifi-only, and I created a new Network location and ensured it was using wifi and connected to my network. The problem persists.

Comment: Hunting for behaviour differences! Could you run the same check on Mac n°1? Could you specify in your initial problem the OS versions of your 2 Macs?